# How to execute a SQL statement against PostgreSQL using SSIS?

Tags: postgresql, ssis

I can't seem to figure out how to execute a sql statement like for example truncate table against a postgresql db using SSIS. I am able to connect to the postgresql db from SSIS just fine.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried execute SQL Task? If you have, please post the error / behaviour that you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding Toolbox **Execute SQL Task**, then edit Toolbox and in tab General fill in the following fields:

- Connection Type: OLE DB
- Connection: choose your postgresql connection
- SQLStatement: insert your query

  That's all.
  I hope this help you.

Comment: One note on this answer, there is a pay-for OLEDB provider for postgres, but the out-of-the-box provider is ODBC.  If you are using ODBC, it would be an ADO.NET connection type for the sql task

Answer (score 1):

Use **Execute SQL Task** and create an ADO.NET Connection instead of ODBC or OLE DB and create a connection for your PostgreSQL.

[image]